# CodeIgniter Models: only for database connection?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, model

Recently, i just joined a company. They are using CodeIgniter PHP and inside the model functions, only database queries are allowed. Loopings and other usages are not allowed to do that.

It's different from what i know. 
Should it be like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well yes and no, the main role of models is to abstract the database layer to the framework, so theoretically speaking, you would only use models to query the database (with active record class or native SQL) and return the result to the controller ,BUT it is not uncommon to see some code like this in a model

```
<?php
//birds_model.php (Array of Strings)
class Birds_model extends CI_Model{
  function get_bird($q){
    $this->db->select('bird');
    $this->db->like('bird', $q);
    $query = $this->db->get('birds');
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
      foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
        $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['bird'])); //build an array
      }
      echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data for the ajax call 
    }
  }
}
```

code ref: [jquery-ui-autocomplete-in-codeigniter-with-database](http://www.codersmount.com/2012/09/jquery-ui-autocomplete-in-codeigniter-with-database/)

that being said, also CodeIgniter has a fairly loose approach to MVC since Models are not required.

If you don't need the added separation, or find that maintaining models requires more complexity than you want, you can ignore them and build your application minimally using Controllers and Views.

CodeIgniter also enables you to incorporate your own existing scripts, or even develop core libraries for the system, enabling you to work in a way that makes the most sense to you.

Ref: [CodeIgniter User Guide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/overview/mvc.html)

I hope that helps you understanding the logic behind codeigniter and you would get used to it ,and just to let you know that opencart for example is using a very similar MVC framework , so learning codeigniter is really nice for broadening your MVC developer skills.

cheers!