# What comes in model...?

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, laravel-5

Hi I am trying to build a to do list in Laravel. It's my first time with a framework. I have actually read a lot of articles about MVC but I don't understand the meaning of model enough, and I want to learn this the correct way. So I have this code and I didn't know where to place it, in a controller or in a model?

```
public function getTask()
{
    $tasks = DB::table('tasks')->get();

    foreach ($tasks as $task) {
        var_dump($task->name);
        var_dump($task->description);
    }
}

public function deleteTask($id)
{
    DB::table('tasks')->where('id',$id)->delete();
}

public function updateTask($id)
{
    DB::table('tasks')
        ->where('id',$id)
        ->update(['votes' => 1]);
}

public function createTask($name,$slug,$description)
{
    DB::table('tasks')->insert(
        ['name' => $name],
        ['slug' => $slug],
        ['description' => $description]
    );
}
```

I am a very new with frameworks so please be patient with my question.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31066445/codeigniter-models-only-for-database-connection/31084181#31084181

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the main role of models is to abstract the database layer to the framework (it is the class that talks to the database), so theoretically speaking, you would only use models to query the database (with active record class or native SQL) and return the result to the controller and the controller will do all the logic work (if...else...etc.) then send it to the view or call a model again to talk to the database ,BUT it is not uncommon in real life to see some logic code in the model althought it is considered as a bad practice in MVC world .you can read more about models for laravel here http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

The code your showing goes in a controller.

Simply said: A model represents your table in your Database and could look as simple as this (User.php);

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but could you give me please an example of code wich goes into model?

Comment: see my edit for a simple user model (representing the users table)

Answer (score 0):

The controller has the logic implementation necessary to read and modify the view through the model.

The model represents all the information that the user can control so it enables the controller access to the view and the view access to the controller, which is called as data-binding.